# c# Webbrowser Invoke Button same

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control

I am trying to invoke a button, now there's three buttons and I am trying to invoke the last one.

All the button classes are the same:
 - class="expedition_button awesome-button "

Only the Onclick is different:

- attack(null, '1', 1, 1, '') First button
- attack(null, '1', 2, 0, '') Second button
- attack(null, '1', 3, 0, '') Third button

How could I target the Third button using the InvokeMember on the Onclick event?
doc.GetElementById("loginsubmit").InvokeMember("Click");

Thanks for taking the time to read. Any help would be appriciated.

Comment: can't just call Submit on the form element or just execute the onclick script?

Comment: Please post the full html for the buttons, once you do that, people will have an idea as to what kind of selector is required to specifically target the third one. In other words, people are going to have to doing something related to targeting the Nth child of a Parent element whose child element contains that class or something similar.